# Static label inside input

Tags: html, css

There is a lot of similar question but I couldn't adjust it to my case.

Here are my goals:

- borderless input list
- static(not disappearing) label on the left side of every input, vertically centered
- value of the input on the right
- applying some effect on focus(border, shadow, etc)
- pure css(I can probably achieve all of these using javascript, but it feels dirty)

I have achieved acceptable effect placing input next to the span, but I can't apply any focus effect on whole row in such way.

Here is an example without focus effect:

[image]

@Edit:

Here is my code for presented output, but as mentioned, it cannot handle focus properly. http://jsfiddle.net/f2znvn4f/

Here is my code for `relative/absolute` solution. The problem is that when focused, label is not affected by effect(and looks like crap). http://jsfiddle.net/kv2uyjbt/1/

Comment: Show some  your markup

Comment: You can't focus a normal div. Isn't focusable. Most tasks you request are very simple and you can achieve perfectly with a single line of CSS. You are not sharing what you are trying so long, that's a rule on stackoverflow if you don't want to see this question closed as offtopic. Share your CSS and HTML and we will edit it to solve your problem. Explain better the desired result.

Comment: Do the label with a DIV

Comment: Okey, it will take me a while, but no problem. I know that div is not focusable, so another way would be to place input behind label, but I could 't do it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: .25em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
input {
  border: none;
  text-align:right;
}
label {
  flex: 1;
}
input:focus,
input:focus + label {
  background: pink;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <label for="">Long Label Goes Here</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <label for="">Short Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the input border-less and the text in it right-adjusted. Then make the label absolute positioned at (0, 0) and wrap both in a div with `position: relative`. Then you should only have to adjust padding of `<label>` and `<input>` to make the texts match in vertical position.

If you have difficulties with it, then post your current code, we should be able to fix that.